# Django post_save preventing recursion without overriding model save()

Tags: python, django, django-signals

There are many Stack Overflow posts about recursion using the `post_save` signal, to which the comments and answers are overwhelmingly: "why not override save()" or a save that is only fired upon `created == True`.

Well I believe there's a good case for not using `save()` - for example, I am adding a temporary application that handles order fulfillment data completely separate from our Order model.

The rest of the framework is blissfully unaware of the fulfillment application and using post_save hooks isolates all fulfillment related code from our Order model.

If we drop the fulfillment service, nothing about our core code has to change. We delete the fulfillment app, and that's it.

So, are there any decent methods to ensure the post_save signal doesn't fire the same handler twice?

Comment: Is this just a rumination, or do you have a specific situation where you've observed multiple firings of the same handler for a single event? E.g. `save()` fires `post_save`, which causes some *other* handler to `save()` the same object again and thus cause another firing of `post_save`?

Comment: @PeterRowell, yes, if your post_save handler needs to save the sender instance, it will trigger post_save again.

Comment: read here with bulk_create you can save without postsave and presave call [django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.bulk_create)

Answer (score 47, accepted):

What you think about this solution?

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=Article)
def generate_thumbnails(sender, instance=None, created=False, **kwargs):

    if not instance:
        return

    if hasattr(instance, '_dirty'):
        return

    do_something()

    try:
        instance._dirty = True
        instance.save()
    finally:
        del instance._dirty
```

You can also create decorator

```
def prevent_recursion(func):

    @wraps(func)
    def no_recursion(sender, instance=None, **kwargs):

        if not instance:
            return

        if hasattr(instance, '_dirty'):
            return

        func(sender, instance=instance, **kwargs)

        try:
            instance._dirty = True
            instance.save()
        finally:
            del instance._dirty

    return no_recursion


@receiver(post_save, sender=Article)
@prevent_recursion
def generate_thumbnails(sender, instance=None, created=False, **kwargs):

    do_something()
```

Comment: Wow, pretty simple and yet smart solution, I think this is the best answer so far. I wish there were more comments on this.

Comment: Can somebody explain what's happening in this solution? I'm struggling to find any documentation for the _dirty flag

Comment: @Max Mumford It is not an flag. To prevent recursion we can set custom attribute before `instance.save()` with any unused name like `_dirty`. Then  check if attribute exists and break the recursion.As you can see we set `_dirty` attribute before we save the model and remove it when saving is done.

Comment: Oops, of course, my bad; I should have looked more carefully at the rest of the function instead of being in a hurry. Thanks 4ell

Comment: It should be the chosen answer.

Comment: Would be even better with a `try...finally` around the call to `instance.save()` to ensure that `del instance._dirty` is always run, even in case of e.g. `DatabaseError`.

Comment: Does this cause a race condition in the case of multiple calls to save with a single instance?

Comment: It might help to show the import `from functools import wraps`

Answer (score 98):

you can use update instead of save in the signal handler

```
queryset.filter(pk=instance.pk).update(....)
```

Comment: Hmm, but what if some *other* signal handler does a `save()` instead of `update()`?

Comment: I wrote this in my post_save signal but it says queryset is not defined error.

Comment: I use this but I have to save my model two times :|

Answer (score 38):

Don't disconnect signals. If any new model of the same type is generated while the signal is disconnected the handler function won't be fired. Signals are global across Django and several requests can be running concurrently, making some fail while others run their post_save handler.

Comment: That's the point. We don't want the signals to run while we are inside the signals.  Besides, signals are not asynchronous.  Check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11899088/is-django-post-save-signal-asynchronous

Comment: Several requests are not handled by the same thread. Signals handlers block only in the thread they are running, that means that if you disconnect a signal handler while OTHER request gets processed, it's signal handlers won't fire. I can't think of a single scenario while you'd want that. P.S. 2018 wow

Comment: Mmm, if we use transaction atomic we don't lose any signal, right?
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/transactions/#controlling-transactions-explicitly

Comment: @mrroot5 AFAIK no, that only assures atomic DB operations, not signal handling. If you disconnect a signal you will loose any signal that is be fired while its disconnected.

Answer (score 29):

I think creating a `save_without_signals()` method on the model is more explicit:

```
class MyModel()
    def __init__():
        # Call super here.
        self._disable_signals = False

    def save_without_signals(self):
        """
        This allows for updating the model from code running inside post_save()
        signals without going into an infinite loop:
        """
        self._disable_signals = True
        self.save()
        self._disable_signals = False

def my_model_post_save(sender, instance, *args, **kwargs):
    if not instance._disable_signals:
        # Execute the code here.
```

Comment: I like it. One suggestion though: instead of overriding `__init__` you could just do `if not getattr(instance, '_disable_signals', False)`

Comment: Is this thread safe? What happens if a regular save is triggered at the same time as a save_without_signals is happening?

Comment: Yes it's thread safe. The ``_disable_signals`` property is local to each model instance.

Comment: Like it. Since the second calling of post save signal does nothing, I hope django will add a parameter in save function, so we can use `instance.save(send_signal=False)`.

Comment: @RuneKaagaard Do you have a reference for `_disable_signals` being local to each model instance? This is fantastic. But I'd love to read/learn more about it.

Comment: @culix It's just how Python works. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5690920/164449

Answer (score 19):

How about disconnecting then reconnecting the signal within your `post_save` function:

```
def my_post_save_handler(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    post_save.disconnect(my_post_save_handler, sender=sender)
    instance.do_stuff()
    instance.save()
    post_save.connect(my_post_save_handler, sender=sender)
post_save.connect(my_post_save_handler, sender=Order)
```

Comment: I had read about this method, and wondered if there was a cleaner solution... I tried leaving attributes on the object being saved to detect if the handler had modified the object once, but it doesn't seem to persist. Any other options?

Comment: I don't believe there is any clean solution.

Comment: hah - I googled my own question and just used this again :) Thanks!

Comment: so when you reconnect, if you have code below the "post_save.connect" in the my_post_save_save_handler, it'll run the rest of the code?

Comment: this is dangerous, while your signal is disconnected instances could be saved and now your handler will be missed.

Comment: This is infact dangerous, so I am going with the update solution as I have used before without issue.

Comment: This helped me again and I cannot +1 it one more time. The update solution doesn't work when you want to update a ManyToMany field.

Comment: This solution is not thread-safe, so concurrent requests can potentially either falsely re-invoke the signal for the save call inside "my_post_save_handler" or falsely not invoke the "my_post_save_handler"  signal in the first place when called outside of ""my_post_save_handler". Would not recommend.

Comment: Not only is this not thread-safe, it is also missing a `try...finally`. Must do the (re)`connect` inside `finally` clause. Without that, if `do_stuff` or `save` raise an exception then your handler will stay disconnected forever...

Answer (score 4):

You should use queryset.update() instead of Model.save() but you need to take care of something else:

It's important to note that when you use it, if you want to use the new object you should get his object again, because it will not change the self object, for example:

```
>>> MyModel.objects.create(pk=1, text='')
>>> el = MyModel.objects.get(pk=1)
>>> queryset.filter(pk=1).update(text='Updated')
>>> print el.text
>>> ''
```

So, if you want to use the new object you should do again:

```
>>> MyModel.objects.create(pk=1, text='')
>>> el = MyModel.objects.get(pk=1)
>>> queryset.filter(pk=1).update(text='Updated')
>>> el = MyModel.objects.get(pk=1) # Do it again
>>> print el.text
>>> 'Updated'
```

Answer (score 4):

You could also check the `raw` argument in `post_save` and then call `save_base`instead of `save`.

Comment: Actually, `save_base` sends the signal; not `save`.

Comment: Of course, but you cannot send ``raw=True`` from the ``save`` method.

Comment: Now I got your point. Keeping this in mind, this is definitely a way to go for me.

Answer (score 1):

the Model's `.objects.update()` method [bypasses the `post_save` signal](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/querysets/#update)

Try this something like this:

```py
from django.db import models
from django.db.models.signals import post_save


class MyModel(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    num_saves = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(default=0)

    @classmethod
    def post_save(cls, sender, instance, created, *args, **kwargs):
        MyModel.objects.filter(id=instance.id).update(save_counter=instance.save_counter + 1)

post_save.connect(MyModel.post_save, sender=MyModel)
```

In this example, an object has a name and each time `.save()` is called, the `.num_saves` property is incremented, but without recursion.

Answer (score 0):

Check this out...

Each signal has it's own benefits as you can read about in the docs here but I wanted to share a couple things to keep in mind with the pre_save and post_save signals.

- Both are called every time .save() on a model is called. In other words, if you save the model instance, the signals are sent.
- running save() on the instance within a post_save can often create a never ending loop and therefore cause a max recursion depth exceeded error --- only if you don't use .save() correctly.
- pre_save is great for changing just instance data because you do not have to call save() ever which eliminates the possibility for above. The reason you don't have to call save() is because a pre_save signal literally means right before being saved.
- Signals can call other signals and or run delayed tasks (for Celery) which can be huge for usability.

Source: https://www.codingforentrepreneurs.com/blog/post-save-vs-pre-save-vs-override-save-method/

Regards!!

Answer (score 0):

**In post_save singal in django for avoiding recursion 'if created' check is  required**

```
from django.dispatch import receiver
from django.db.models.signals import post_save

@receiver(post_save, sender=DemoModel)
def _post_save_receiver(sender,instance,created, **kwargs):
    if created:            
       print('hi..')
       instance.save()
```

Answer (score 0):

I was using the `save_without_signals()` method by @Rune Kaagaard until i updated my Django to 4.1. On Django 4.1 this method started raising an Integrity error on the database that gave me 4 days of headaches and i couldn't fix it.

So i started to use the `queryset.update()` method and it worked like a charm. It doesn't trigger the `pre_save()` neither `post_save()` and you don't need to override the `save()` method of your model. 1 line of code.

```
@receiver(pre_save, sender=Your_model)
def any_name(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    Your_model.objects.filter(pk=instance.pk).update(model_attribute=any_value)
```