# Update value of a certail column in django post_save signals

Tags: python, django

I have a class Video whose structure is as below:

```
class Video(models.Model):
    video = models.FileField(upload_to="media_items/video", blank=True)
    video_mp4 = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=500)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return unicode(self.video.name) or u''
```

and signals.py is as

```
@receiver(post_save, sender = Video)
def insert_video_mp4(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if os.path.exists(created_path):
        #some code
    else:
        #some code to insert value in video_mp4 column
```

I want to update the value of video_mp4 as explained above in post_save signals.
Please let me know how to achieve this.
I am getting the below error

```
RuntimeError at /admin/blog/video/8/change/
maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/admin/blog/video/8/change/
Django Version: 1.10.5
Exception Type: RuntimeError
Exception Value:    
maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object
Exception Location: /Users/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py in __eq__, line 462
Python Executable:  /Users/anaconda2/bin/python
Python Version: 2.7.15
Python Path:    
['/Users/TechnopleSolutions/Desktop/matrix-server-master',
 '/Users/anaconda2/lib/python27.zip',
 '/Users/anaconda2/lib/python2.7',
 '/Users/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/plat-darwin',
 '/Users/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/plat-mac',
 '/Users/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages',
 '/Users/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/Users/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
 '/Users/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
 '/Users/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages',
 '/Users/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/aeosa']
```

Comment: Why do you need signals here? What's your logic ? Can you explain it?

Comment: I am doing some operation after that I'm updating the column

Comment: try my answer, updated it

Comment: Its a funny problem. The 'Stack is Overflowing' because of recursive save call and post_save call.

Comment: @JerinPeterGeorge thanks buddy working now.

Comment: @daemon mark the answer if so :)

Answer (score 2):

**`instance`** is corresponding **`Video`** object here.

```
@receiver(post_save, sender = Video)
def insert_video_mp4(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if os.path.exists(created_path):
        #some code
    else:
        instance.video_mp4="some value"
        instance.save()
```

**UPDATE**
The above solution will cause a `maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object` error. So, do your logic **`save()`** method of model by overriding it as,

```
class Video(models.Model):
    video = models.FileField(upload_to="media_items/video", blank=True)
    video_mp4 = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=500)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if os.path.exists(created_path):
        # some code
        else:
            self.video_mp4 = "some text"
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return unicode(self.video.name) or u''
```

**Note**:
It's not a good idea to call **`.save()`** method inside a `post_save` signal

Comment: I have tried this but getting error as "Exception Value: 
maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object"

Comment: can you add full traceback to your question ?

Comment: @daemon Did you override anything?

Comment: No, not overriding anything

Comment: Ok. Why do you need signals here? What's your logic ? Can you explain it?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Jerin Peter George
But found a very good solution for that

[Check this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10840030/django-post-save-preventing-recursion-without-overriding-model-save)