# How do I set a ManyToMany field on post_save of a model?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-signals

I have a model, say, `Ticket`. The `Ticket` has `Tag` as ManyToMany field among the other fields.

After somebody updates any field of `Ticket` (say `Description`), I want to set the `Tag` field value to one of the existing tags.

How do I do this?

Answer (score -1):

Use Django signals

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=Ticket)
def create_tag(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if not created:
        instance.tags.add(Tag.objects.get(id=1)) #Add an existing tag
        instance.save()

post_save.connect(create_tag, sender=Ticket)
```

Comment: Why are you suggesting to add tag only if  `created` is `True`?

Comment: tag is a manytomany field inside Ticket .. Why do you want to add tag without a Ticket instance? If you remove created also the code will run,just a more organised way to do it

Comment: Can't we add a tag on update of Ticket? I believe created is true if it is a newly created ticket, correct me!

Comment: I edited my answer..ALso post_save would be called if  .save() is called.  Does not get called on .update()

Comment: Is there any to avoid infinite recursion caused by calling .save() wihtin post_save?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10840030/django-post-save-preventing-recursion-without-overriding-model-save    
@vignz.pie