# How to prevent recursion in django post_save signal?

Tags: django, django-models

I tried this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/28369908/9902571 in my model and done the following :-

```
from functools import wraps

def prevent_recursion(func):

        @wraps(func)
        def no_recursion(sender, instance=None, **kwargs):

            if not instance:
                return

            if hasattr(instance, '_dirty'):
                return

            func(sender, instance=instance, **kwargs)

            try:
                instance._dirty = True
                instance.save()
            finally:
                del instance._dirty

        return no_recursion
```

My model:

```
class Journal(models.Model):
    user            = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True,blank=True)
    company         = models.ForeignKey(company,on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True,blank=True,related_name='Companyname')
    date            = models.DateField(default=datetime.date.today)
    voucher_id      = models.PositiveIntegerField(blank=True,null=True)
    by              = models.ForeignKey(ledger1,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='Debitledgers')
    to              = models.ForeignKey(ledger1,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='Creditledgers')
    debit           = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10,decimal_places=2,null=True)
    credit          = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10,decimal_places=2,null=True)
```

My signal:

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=journal)
@prevent_recursion
def pl_journal(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        if instance.by.group1_Name.group_Name == 'Indirect Expense':
            Journal.objects.update_or_create(user=instance.user,company=instance.company,date=instance.date, voucher_id=instance.id, voucher_type= "Journal",by=instance.by,to=ledger1.objects.filter(user=instance.user,company=instance.company,name__icontains='Profit & Loss A/c').first(),debit=instance.debit,credit=instance.credit)
```

But the RecursionError of `maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object` stills comes while creating a journal object.

I want to pass the post_save signal for the same model `(Journal)` which when matches the condition in the signal gets called recursively.

Any anyone tell me what is wrong in my code?

Thank you

Comment: did you try to set the `instance._dirty = True` before call `func(sender, instance=instance, **kwargs)` inside wrapper?

Comment: Yeah I set the `_dirty` attribute before I save the model

Comment: add ` dispatch_uid` in `@receiver(post_save, sender=journal)` [link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/signals/#preventing-duplicate-signals)

Comment: The error still comes @Shakil.

Comment: can you please remove `prevent_recursion` decorator and try.

Answer (score 0):

It is a little late but it may help others too. Instead of this, you can add dispatch_uid="identifier" to signal and it will work fine.

```
post_save.connect(function_name, sender=Model, dispatch_uid="identifier")
```

or

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=Model, dispatch_uid="identifier")
```

doc: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/signals/#preventing-duplicate-signals