# How to fetch certain field value of related models object and save it to another?

Tags: django, django-models, orm

My models **`Book`** and **`ReadList`** related and I can use them on Django Admin but I want to fetch **`bookPageCount`** field of selected object and save it to **`pageCount`** field of new object when save.

```py
from django.db import models
from django.db.models.signals import post_save, pre_save
from django.dispatch import receiver

# Create your models here.

class Book(models.Model):
    bookname = models.CharField(max_length=200, verbose_name='Kitap Adı')
    bookAuthor = models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name='Yazar Adı')
    bookPublisher = models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name='Yayın Evi')
    bookPageCount = models.PositiveIntegerField(verbose_name='Sayfa Sayısı')
    bookAddDate = models.DateField(verbose_name='Kitaplığa Eklenme Tarihi')
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Kitap'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Kitaplar'
    def __str__(self):
        return self.bookname

class ReadList(models.Model):
    bookName = models.ForeignKey('kitaplik.Book', related_name='book', on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='Kitap Adı')
    readerName = models.ForeignKey('ogrenciler.Students', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='readerName', verbose_name='Okuyan Kişi')
    dateOfRead = models.DateField(verbose_name='Okuma Tarihi')
    pageCount = models.PositiveIntegerField(verbose_name='Sayfa Sayısı',blank=True, null=True)
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Okuma Günlüğü'

@receiver(post_save, sender=ReadList)
def get_pageCount(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    instance.pageCount = instance.Book.bookPageCount
    instance.save
```

**EDIT**: Changes been made after Higor's reminder but I still have problem as the same. The error I get is `'ReadList' object has no attribute 'Book'`

Comment: `instance.save()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`bookName` is the field name

```py
@receiver(post_save, sender=ReadList)
def get_pageCount(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    instance.pageCount = instance.bookName.bookPageCount
    instance.save()
```

Comment: Yes this worked and led to another error. My new code;
`instance.pageCount = instance.bookName.bookPageCount`
And the new error is `maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison`

Comment: you can follow this comment. https://stackoverflow.com/a/28369908/1811771

Answer (score 1):

I think you've mistaken some names.

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=ReadList)
def get_pageCount(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    instance.pageCount = instance.book.bookpageCount
    instance.save()
```

Comment: Yeah thank you for reminder but actually my problem is a bit different. I am getting an error as below;
`'ReadList' object has no attribute 'book'`

Comment: the fieldname should be `bookName`