# A function returns another function. Why the function inside can scope a list from the parent but not a constant?

Tags: python, scoping

Consider this function:

```
def g():
    x = []
    
    def f():
        x.append([0])
        print(x)
        pass
    return f
```

Calling it:

```
test = g()
test()
```

I get the following output:

```
Out: [[0]]
```

We can reinitialize the test function and call it multiple times:

```
test = g()
for i in range(3):
    test()
```

Resulting in the following output:

```
Out: [[0]]
[[0], [0]]
[[0], [0], [0]]
```

However, defining the following function:

```
def j():
    x = 1
    def f():
        x += 1
        print(x)
        pass
    return f
```

And calling it:

```
test = j()
test()
```

Results in an error:

```
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'x' referenced before assignment
```

The list seems to be in the inner function scope while the value is not. Why is this happening?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why can't Python increment variable in closure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21959985/why-cant-python-increment-variable-in-closure)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@rassar clearly explained the reason. Here I give a solution:

```py
def j():
    x = 1
    def f():
        nonlocal x
        x += 1
        print(x)
        pass
    return f
```

Actually this is not a simple question. Even though `+=` looks like a bounded method call, an in-place operation (if you have experience in other languages). But what runs under is something like `x = x.__add__(1)` or `x = x.__iadd__(1)`. So this is an assignment.

Comment: Thank you! Why assignment expression are not callable inside the child function but method calls are?

Comment: It's because python mixed the creation and use of variables. That is, `x = y` may refer to "creating a variable `x` with value `y`" or "assign value `y` to existing variable `x`".  Calling a method is deterministic, meaning "use". `x = y` is also deterministic, meaning "creation". But `x += y` is ambiguous. There are both "creation" and "use" and Python thinks they referred to the same variable.

Comment: UPD: `x = y` is also deterministic, but depending on the context. When it first comes up in a scope, it means "creation". So `x += y` i.e. `x = x + y` uses the inner scope variable `x` rather than outer `x`. @deppep

Comment: @QuarticCat `x += y` isn't ambiguous it is simply both.

Answer (score 1):

This is because `j` uses an assignment expression, where `g` uses a method call. Remember that `x += 1` is equivalent to `x = x + 1`. If you change `g` to:

```py
def g():
    x = []

    def f():
        x += [[0]]
        print(x)
        pass
    return f
```

You get:

```py
>>> test = g()
>>> test()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#20>", line 1, in <module>
    test()
  File "<pyshell#18>", line 5, in f
    x += [[0]]
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'x' referenced before assignment
```

Comment: Thank you. Why assignment expression are not callable inside the child function but method calls are?

Comment: @deppep assignment *marks a variable as **local** at **compile time***. So if you don't want it to be treated as local, you need to use either `nonlocal` or `global`. This is the same even with un-nested functions.

Answer (score 0):

Because, the python complier knows that the variable 'x' in function f is a local variable not in the function j. So the error you mentioned above is occurred.

So you should use nonlocal. Please refer the link below.
[Accessing parent function's variable in a child function called in the parent using python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40687309/accessing-parent-functions-variable-in-a-child-function-called-in-the-parent-us)