# How does del interact with object attributes?

Tags: python, memory-management, attributes

I'm new to Python and saw this code snippet:

```
class C:
    abc = 2

c1 = C()
print c1.abc

c1.abc = 3
print c1.abc

del c1.abc
print c1.abc
```

I understand why the first and the second print statements print 2, respectively 3. Coming from a Java background however, I don't understand what happens in the line '`del c1.abc`' and why the last print statement prints 2 and not some kind of an error. Can someone explain? If possible by comparing to Java?

Comment: @Aaron I don't understand how this is even slightly related to my question. Can you elaborate?

Comment: The sticky issue to a Python beginner here is that `abc` is a *class variable* (i.e. a "static" variable), and when you do `c1.abc = 3`, you *shadow* the class variable with an instance variable. When you do `del c1.abc` the `del` applies to the *instance* variable, so calling `c1.abc` now returns the class variable.

Comment: @Aaron but that isn't what's going on here.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Tha's exactly the answer I was looking for! Thanks! Can you copy that to an actual answer? Then I could upvote and accept :)

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga true, I'll remove my comment.. yours is much more relevant

Comment: So, do the same thing as above, but create a new instance `c = C()`. Now try `del c.abc` and you'll get an error.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga: Bad dupe. It doesn't say anything about the interaction of `del` and object attributes; it's all about memory management and ordinary variables.

Comment: @Aaron this is a duplicate, one way or another, so I'd rather just let it be dupe-targetd.

Comment: @user6189 it's sort of a combination of that one and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5690888/variable-scopes-in-python-classes) one. Perhaps a gold-tagger coudl add the second target too.

Comment: Fine, I guess I'll just post my comment as an answer if y'all don't think this is a duplicate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sticky issue to a Python beginner here is that `abc` is a class variable (i.e. a "static" variable), and when you do `c1.abc = 3`, you *shadow the class variable with an instance variable*. When you do `del c1.abc` the `del` applies to the *instance variable*, so calling `c1.abc` now returns the class variable.

The following interactive session should clear some things up:

```
>>> class C:
...   abc = 2
...
>>> c1 = C()
>>> c2 = C()
>>> c1.abc = 3
>>> c1.abc
3
>>> c2.abc
2
>>> C.abc # class "static" variable
2
>>> del c1.abc
>>> c1.abc
2
>>> c2.abc
2
>>> C.abc
2
>>> del c2.abc
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: C instance has no attribute 'abc'
>>> del C.abc
>>> c1.abc
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: C instance has no attribute 'abc'
>>>
```

It is `del.<someattribute>` always deletes the *instance* attribute. It won't delete a class-level attribute if applied to an instance, instead, you have to apply it to the class!

In Python, everything written inside a class block is *always at the class level*. In this sense, it is simpler than Java. To define an instance variable, you need to assign directly to an instance, outisde a method (`c1.abc = 3`) or inside a method, using the first parameter passed to that method (by *convention* this is called `self` but could be `banana` if you wanted):

```
>>> class C:
...    def some_method(banana, x): # by convention you should use `self` instead of `banana`
...         banana.x = x
...
>>> c = C()
>>> c.x
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: C instance has no attribute 'x'
>>> c.some_method(5)
>>> c.x
5
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This clears many things up!

Comment: @user6189 I added a little bit about class-level variables in Python. It is helpful to read through the [official tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html). Python class definitions are really simple, but they work a little differently than a Java class definition.