# Class variable vs instance variable

Tags: python

While learning python through python docs, i came across the following wherein its explained that class variable is common to the class and that any object can change it:

**Sample Code 1:**

```
class Dog:

    tricks = []             # mistaken use of a class variable
        def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def add_trick(self, trick):
        self.tricks.append(trick)
```

**Output:**

```
>>> d = Dog('Fido')
>>> e = Dog('Buddy')
>>> d.add_trick('roll over')
>>> e.add_trick('play dead')
>>> d.tricks                # unexpectedly shared by all dogs
['roll over', 'play dead']
```

Question => If so, then why doesn't `y` in the following example get affected when `x` changes its `tricks` attribute to 5?

**Sample Code 2:**

```
class Complex:
    tricks = 3
    def __init__(self,var1):
        self.tricks=var1

    def add_tricks(self,var1):
        self.tricks=var1

x = Complex(11)
y = Complex(12)
print (x.tricks)
print (y.tricks)

x.add_tricks(5)
print (x.tricks)
print (y.tricks) -->Remains unchanged
```

**Output:**

```
11
12
5
12 -->Remains unchanged
```

And what exactly is the difference when i remove the `self` in the following program:

**Sample Code 3:**

```
class Complex:
    tricks = 3
    def __init__(self,var1):
        self.tricks=var1

    def add_tricks(self,var1):
        tricks=var1

x = Complex(11)
y = Complex(12)
print (x.tricks)
print (y.tricks)

x.add_tricks(5) -->This change is not reflected anywhere
print (x.tricks)
print (y.tricks)
print(Complex.tricks)
```

**Output:**

```
11
12
11
12
3
```

Comment: In the first case you are *modifying* a list in the classes namespace that is just accessed via `self`. In the seconds case you are *assigning* a values to `self.tricks` in the namespace of the instance. This will overwrite any earlier value.

Comment: See first two points of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5690920/2201041)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This example may be illustrative.  Given the following class (I've dropped the initialiser from your example because it doesn't let us demonstrate the behaviour):

```py
class Complex:
    tricks = 3
    def add_tricks(self, value):
        self.tricks = value
```

We can see, upon creation, the value of their `tricks` attribute is both `3`:

```
>>> a = Complex()
>>> b = Complex()
>>> 
>>> a.tricks
3
>>> b.tricks
3
```

Let's take a second and look at the names defined on those objects:

```py
>>> a.__dict__
{}
>>> b.__dict__
{}
```

They're both objects with no attributes themselves.  Let's see what happens after we call `add_tricks` on `b`:

```py
>>> b.add_tricks(5)
>>>   
>>> a.tricks
3
>>> b.tricks
5
```

Okay.  So, this looks like the shared value hasn't been affected.  Let's take a look at their names again:

```py
>>> a.__dict__
{}
>>> b.__dict__
{'tricks': 5}
```

And there it is.  Assigning to `self.tricks` creates an attribute local to that object with name `tricks`, which when accessed via the object (or `self`) is the one that we'll use from that point forward.

The shared value is still there and unchanged:

```py
>>> a.__class__.tricks
3
>>> b.__class__.tricks
3
```

It's just on the class, not on the object.